# Null Pointer Exception Thrown

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I am making a dynamic JComboBox which reads the value from a CSV file and put in it. I am able to get the desired values from the file. However when I am trying to put the fetched value in another array to put it in the combobox it's giving me NullPointerException. Here is the code:

```
        String[] val = null;
        String[] val2 = null;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("rinku.csv");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine; 
            int i=0;
           while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                 val = strLine.split(",");
                 val2[i]=val[2]; //NullPointerException thrown here
                //System.out.println(val[2]);
                //String[] options={"op1","op2"};
                 i++;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
        jb= new JComboBox(val2);
        contentPane.add(jb);
```

Is there is any other way I can put those val[2] values in my JComboBox?

Answer (score 2):

You never assigned `val2`.
Additionally, next time attach stack-trace and use the error for the first debugging process.

Comment: I used val2 since I have to put val[2] values in it and redirect it in  JComboBox.

Comment: @user3502063 Your code doesn't show it. It seems that `val2` is null and invoking `[i]` on null like `null[i]` will throw NPE.

Comment: Yeah. I just made a small change according to a deleted answer String[] val2= new String[size]; and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

val[2] is throwing the NullPointerException for sure.

First, check the length for string array val, then you will realize the actual thing behind this error.

```
val[].length // check if it is greater than zero or not. If Yes  - Loop it and check the value for 2.
```

Ideally , Most of the cases NullPointerException or ArrayOutofBoundException are thrown in this cases.

Comment: Yes for val[2] there exists values. Since I initialized with null only it was throwing NullPointerException. I changed it a bit as in above comment and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting the value in an Array?

You can just use:

```
comboBox.addItem(...);
```